# How to visualize 95% confidence interval in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics

I have learned how to find the 95% confidence interval with `scipy.stats.t` like so

```
In [1]: from scipy.stats import t
In [2]: t.interval(0.95, 10, loc=1, scale=2)  # 95% confidence interval
Out[2]: (-3.4562777039298762, 5.4562777039298762)
In [3]: t.interval(0.99, 10, loc=1, scale=2)  # 99% confidence interval
Out[3]: (-5.338545334351676, 7.338545334351676)
```

However, visualization is important to me. I am wondering how may I show the confidence interval bar on each node of my curve in `matplotlib`?

What I am expecting is something like this

[image]

Comment: `errorbar`?  Have you tried anything?  Have you looked at the gallery?

Comment: @tcaswell by error bar I mean the `工` shape at each point in the plot.

Comment: I believe @tcaswell is referring to [the matplotlib function called `errorbar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar).  Have you tried using it?  [Here is a worked example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/errorbar_demo_features.html)

Comment: Note that if you use `errorbar`, it expects the _size_ of the error, not the _limits_, so you'll want to subtract the mean from both values in your interval.  That is, if your interval is `(-2, 5)` around `2`, that translates to `2 - 4 / + 3 ` for `errorbar` input.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need `.interval` method, to get the *size* of confidence interval, you just need the `.ppf` method.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as ss
data_m=np.array([1,2,3,4])   #(Means of your data)
data_df=np.array([5,6,7,8])   #(Degree-of-freedoms of your data)
data_sd=np.array([11,12,12,14])   #(Standard Deviations of your data)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.errorbar([0,1,2,3], data_m, yerr=ss.t.ppf(0.95, data_df)*data_sd)
plt.xlim((-1,4))
```

`ss.t.ppf(0.95, data_df)*data_sd` is a fully vectorize way to get the (half) size of interval, given the degrees of freedom and standard deviation.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you also divide standard deviations by the square root of the degrees of freedom: i.e. ```ss.t.ppf(0.95, data_df)*data_sd/np.sqrt(data_df)``` instead?

Comment: @Anis Yes! because standard error is sample standard deviation divided by sqrt(n), where n is sample size.

Answer (score 0):

you need to divide by standard deviation, and, second, if your data is two-sided (as plot suggests), you need to allow 2.5% of misses on each side of Gaussian, that is:

```
ss.t.ppf(0.975, data_df)/np.sqrt(data_df)
```

Since you miss 2.5% on both sides, you get total 5% miss.

Comment: The question asks: "I am wondering how may I show the confidence interval bar on each node of my curve in `matplotlib`?". Please edit your answer to actually answer the question.

Comment: In my opinion, "how" involves two things: mathematical equation and practical implementation. While the practical part was answered above, I only showed the correct mathematical part here. See previous answer and @Anis comment to it.